# Tem como colocar uma array numa variável em JavaScript e comparar com o valor no campo texto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o código abaixo e preciso pegar vários valores distintos de uma vez. Uma maneira que pensei foi em array mais não funciona. Depois do Ajax ele me traz o resulta no `id` `zpl`, se o resultado vier vazio ele retorna o aviso que não tem o valor no banco. Até ai tudo bem, só que eu gostaria também que se o resultado vier `SD10` e `SD11` e por aí vai, também apareça a mesma mensagem da condição vazio, porém gostaria de não poder colocar vários *ous* `||` na condição e colocar os valores dentro de uma variável em array e fazer a comparação no

```
var variavel = new array('valor1','valor2');
document.getElementById('zpl').value == variavel;
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Gostaria de pegar vários valores e colocar dentro de uma variável e na hora de fazer a validação com o comando `document.getElementById('valor do campo').value ==` a variável que está com esses valores. Eu tentei:

```
var arr = new array("s10","s11","s12","s13");

document.getElementById('valor do campo').value = arr
```

Ou seja, vai comparar o valor do campo texto da página com os valores das variáveis armazenadas na variável `arr` .

Alguém sabe fazer isso em JavaScript?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "label_query.php",
    data: {
        serial: $('#serial').val(),
        combox: $("#combox").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#zpl').html(data);

        var arr = new array('SD10', 'SD11', 'SD12');

        if (document.getElementById('zpl').value == '' || document.getElementById('zpl').value == arr) {

            alert('NÂO HÁ REGISTRO DESSE SERIAL NO BANCO DE DADOS!');
            document.getElementById('serial').value = '';
            document.getElementById("bSubmit").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("bSubmit").value = "Enviar";
            document.getElementById("serial").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            criarArquivo();
            document.getElementById("bSubmit").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("bSubmit").value = "Enviar";
            document.getElementById("serial").focus();
        }
```

Comment: utilize http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: O que dá `console.log(data);` na primeira linha do `success: function(data) {`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `indexOf` da seguinte forma:

```js
function contem() {
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var arr = ['ASD', 'DEF', 'GHI'];
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (arr.indexOf(valor) > -1 ? 'Contem o valor digitado' : 'Nao Contem');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valor">
<button onclick="contem()">Testar</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Um detalhe muito importante para citar é que essa sua arquitetura poderia estar melhor planejada, explico:
Quando o backend nao encontra um registro, ele SEMPRE deve retornar um erro e nunca um sucesso.

Daí você não teria que tratar soluções distintas em cantos iguais. É apenas uma dica de melhoria.

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizaria apenas desta forma:

```
['s10','s11','s12','s13'].indexOf(document.getElementById('zpl').value) !== -1;
```

O resultado desta linha seria `true` caso o valor do campo seja algum destes no array, do contrário, seria `false`

Answer (score 0):

Você deve transformar o array em uma string e então comparar com o value

#### Substitua:

```
var arr = new array("s10","s11","s12","s13");
```

#### Por

```
var arr = ['s10', 's11', 's12', 's13'].join("");
```

#### Então

```
document.getElementById('zpl').value == arr;
```